# Deciphering text in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take a text as input, count the number of occurrences of each alphabetic letter in the string, so for example in "hello" h =1 , e =1 , l =2, o =1 . and then replace the highest occurring letter with E and second highest with T and so on from here (http://www.counton.org/explorer/codebreaking/frequency-analysis.php)
So am trying to do this in python 3 , and so far I made a code the takes the text as input and counts the number of occurrences of each alphabet, but my problem is in the replacing part. Can any one help me in doing this, how do I replace the highest occurring alphabet with the highest occurring one according to that website?

Here is my code (sorry about that):

```
def break_cipher(OriginalText = input()):
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
f=0
g=0
h=0
i=0
j=0
k=0
l=0
m=0
n=0
o=0
p=0
q=0
r=0
s=0
t=0
u=0
v=0
w=0
x=0
y=0
z=0
for charr in OriginalText:
    if charr  == 'a' :
        a +=1
    if charr  == 'b' :
        b +=1
    if charr  == 'c' :
        c +=1
    if charr  == 'd' :
        d +=1
    if charr  == 'e' :
        e +=1
    if charr  == 'f' :
        f +=1
    if charr  == 'g' :
        g +=1
    if charr  == 'h' :
        h +=1
    if charr  == 'i' :
        i +=1
    if charr  == 'j' :
        j +=1
    if charr  == 'k' :
        k +=1
    if charr  == 'l' :
        l +=1
    if charr  == 'm' :
        m +=1
    if charr  == 'n' :
        n +=1
    if charr  == 'o' :
        o +=1
    if charr  == 'p' :
        p +=1
    if charr  == 'q' :
        q +=1
    if charr  == 'r' :
        r +=1
    if charr  == 's' :
        s +=1
    if charr  == 't' :
        t +=1
    if charr  == 'u' :
        u +=1
    if charr  == 'v' :
        v +=1
    if charr  == 'w' :
        w +=1
    if charr  == 'x' :
        x +=1
    if charr  == 'y' :
        y +=1
    if charr  == 'z' :
        z +=1
mylist = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v]
mylist.sort()
print(mylist)
print(mylist[-1])
str(OriginalText)
print("a = " + str(a))
print("b = " +str(b))
print("c = " +str(c))
print("d = " +str(d))
print("e = " +str(e))
print("f = " +str(f))
print("g = " +str(g))
print("h = " +str(h))
print("i = " +str(i))
print("j = " +str(j))
print("k = " +str(k))
print("l = " +str(l))
print("m = " +str(m))
print("n = " +str(n))
print("o = " +str(o))
print("p = " +str(p))
print("q = " +str(q))
print("r = " +str(r))
print("s = " +str(s))
print("t = " +str(t))
print("u = " +str(u))
print("v = " +str(v))
print("w = " +str(w))
print("x = " +str(x))
print("y = " +str(y))
print("z = " +str(z))
```

break_cipher()

Comment: can you show us the code ? what input you are giving, what output you are getting, and what output you were expecting. Also any errors which occur, and or any other information which could help us to help you.

Comment: wow! This can be done in maybe 2-3 rows but you managed over 100 :D. I'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
from collections import Counter

def break_cipher(text):
    letters = sorted(Counter(text).items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    text = text.replace(letters[0][0],'E').replace(letters[1][0],'T')
    return text

break_cipher('hello')
```

Returns:

```
'TeEEo'
```

---

This works because Counter(text) equals:

```
Counter({'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1})
```

And the variable `letters` is a list with these sorted:

```
[('l', 2), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('o', 1)]
```

the `'l'` becomes `'E'` and the `'h'` becomes `'T'`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a function call as default value, because what that means is you are calling input() when you DEFINE the function, not when you call it. This input() will be called once, and only once, and this will happen when you import the module, not when you call the function.

```
def break_cipher(OriginalText):
```

Do not name a variable in CamelCase, nor start it in capital letters (that's the convention for classes)

```
def break_cipher(original_text)
```

Use a dict instead of these many variables:

```
count_dict = {}
```

Your task is to iterate through the string, use a loop:

```
for character in original_text:
    if character not in count_dict:
        count_dict[character] = 0
    count_dict += 1
```

At the end of the loop you will have something like:

```
{
    'a': 5,
    'e': 7
 }
```

Etc...

You can also use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that will simplify your code further

```
from collections import defaultdict

count_dict = defaultdict(int)  # Note that new int's are 0 

for character in original_text:
    count_dict[character] += 1
```

There are many subtilities and improvements possible:

Is A == a? in that case you want to do:

```
count_dict[character.lower()] += 1
```

Are you intended to only count english alphabet characters ? in that case you need to:

```
for character in [charr for charr in count_dict if 'a' < charr.lower() < 'z']
```

(see [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) for this one)

For the replacement part:

```
frequencies = count_dict.keys()  # This gives you a list of all the letters in the text
frequencies.sort(key=count_dict).reverse()  # This will sort them by frequency
```

Then you just need to recreate the text from there

May the code be with you

Comment: Could you please explain me why one should not use a function call as a default value, dear @Luis Sieira ?

Comment: I edited the answer. Actually, this code, will get stuck before doing anything until input exits (you press enter) and whatever value you send at that point will become the default value of your method